# Evaluating a lift operator

Tags: numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces, finite-element-method, galerkin-methods

In a lot of papers discussing discontinuous Galerkin methods for solving elliptic/parabolic PDE's, they mention a "lift" operator.

For example, consider a simple Poisson system:
\begin{gather}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{\sigma} = f\\
\mathbf{\sigma} = \nabla u
\end{gather}
with an appropriate choice of boundary conditions (not of concern here).

In [Arnold et al.'s paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0036142901384162), they define a lift operator as such:

Suppose you have two non-overlapping subsets of a domain $\Omega$ denoted as the $K_0$ and the $K_1$ subsets such that $\Omega
 = K_0 \cup K_1$, and a shared interface $\Gamma = K_0 \cap K_1$.

Then they define "lift" operators to be some functions $r(\phi) : [L^2(\Gamma)]^2 \rightarrow \Sigma_h$ and $l(\phi) : L^2(\Gamma) \rightarrow \Sigma_h$ such that for all $\tau \in \Sigma_h$,

\begin{gather}
\int_\Omega r(\phi) \cdot \tau dV = - \int_\Gamma \phi \cdot \frac{\tau|_{K_0} + \tau|_{K_1}}{2} dS\\
\int_\Omega l(\phi) \cdot \tau dV = - \int_\Gamma \phi (\tau|_{K_0} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}|_{K_0} + \tau|_{K_1} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}|_{K_1}) dS
\end{gather}
where
\begin{gather}
\Sigma_h := \{\tau \in [L^2(\Omega)]^2 : \tau|_T \in \Sigma(T)~~~ \forall T \in \{K_0, K_1\}\}\\
\Sigma(T) = [P_p(T)]^2,
\end{gather}
$P_p(T)$ is the space of polynomial functions of degree at most $p \ge 1$,
and $\tau|_K$ indicates the function $\tau$ evaluated at the interface inside of $K$, and $\tau|_T$ indicates the function $\tau$ evaluated at the interface inside of $T$.

As far as I can tell, the function $r(\phi)$ and $l(\phi)$ are just notation to allow a surface integral to be re-written as a volume integral, and I am unsure of what other properties these function have, or even how to evaluate them, but this wasn't detrimental for implementing most methods.

However, now I am trying to make sense of another paper by [Peraire et al.](http://persson.berkeley.edu/pub/peraire07cdg.pdf) which now defines a numerical flux in terms of a "facewise" lift operator (which in the context of this example domain, is exactly the same, i.e. $r^e(\phi) = r(\phi)$ and $l^e(\phi) = l(\phi)$ only because there is exactly one shared interface). In particular, they define (condensed with $C_{11} = 0$ for brevity)
\begin{gather}
\hat{\mathbf{\sigma}} = \frac{\mathbf{\sigma}^e_h|_{K_0} + \mathbf{\sigma}^e_h|_{K_1}}{2} + \mathbf{C}_{12} (\mathbf{\sigma}^e_h|_{K_0} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}_{K_0} + \mathbf{\sigma}^e_h|_{K_1} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}_{K_1})\\
\mathbf{\sigma}^e_h = \nabla_h u_h + r^e\left(
\frac{u_h|_{K_0} + u_h|_{K_1}}{2}\right)
+ l^e\left(
u_h|_{K_0} \hat{\mathbf{n}}|_{K_0} + u_h|_{K_1} \hat{\mathbf{n}}|_{K_1}\right)
\end{gather}

To implement this numerically, there is a term which requires me to compute
\begin{gather}
\int_\Gamma \hat{\sigma} \cdot (v|_{K_0} \hat{\mathbf{n}}|_{K_0} + v|_{K_1} \hat{\mathbf{n}}|_{K_1}) dS
\end{gather}
where $v$ is a test function defined in $L^2(\Omega)$ restricted to the subsets $K_0$ or $K_1$.

I am at a complete loss as to what it even means to take a surface integral of a lift operator, or even how to do this. So that's my question:

1. What are these lift operators $r(\phi)$ and $l(\phi)$, beyond just a convenient way to transform surface integrals into volume integrals?
2. How would I go about evaluating the above surface integral of lift operators?

Comment: Could you add the definition of $\Sigma$? Maybe, one can consider lift operators as solution operators for some local element problems -consider the integrals in the left side of their definitions as bilinear forms and the righthand side as a linear bounded functional. Then you can solve them and find values $r(\varphi)$ and $l(\varphi)$. Though I have never dealt with them, so it is just a guess.

Comment: @VorKir added the definition of $\Sigma$

Comment: So, can't you just consider the definition of lift operators as a system of equations? You have, e.g., unknown $r(\varphi)$ from $\Sigma_h$ and can vary $\tau$ in $\Sigma_h$, e.g., taking the simplest basis for $\Sigma_h$. Then you will get a small linear system to find $r(\varphi)$ for your particular $\varphi$ which is related to $u_h$. Then, as it is said in the paper  $\sigma_h^e$ (which includes lift operators) is nonzero in only one element neighbouring the considered face. So you will take values of $r(\varphi)$ in this element on the considered face.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, I'll mess around with that and see how that works in actual code. Thanks!

Comment: Hope this helps! Please make a comment about the results of your tryings.